# How can I customize the style of my DataGrid from a theme with Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a  imported from Material UI to which I assign the styles as follows:

```
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    color: theme.palette.common.white
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14
  }
}));
```

I want my DataGrid to have the same styles but I don't know how to add them, in this case I can't use `headerClassName`, I need use theme.palette.secondary.main

This is my table:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIAmL.png)

And I have this DataGrid:
[DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrEr.png)

I need my DataGrid looks like my Table.